# How to make $\sqrt{\det(A^TA)}$ into a function that is multilinear in the columns of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

The determinant $\det(A)$ is an alternating multilinear form in the columns of $A$. Given vectors $\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_n\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we can interpret $|\det(A)|$ as the volume of the parallelotope generated by $\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_n$. More precisely, $\det(A)$ is the ''signed volume'' of the parallelotope.

Now consider $k$ vectors $\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_k\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $A$ be the $n\times k$ matrix with these columns. Then $\sqrt{\det(A^TA)}$ is the $k$-volume of the $k$-parallelotope generated by $\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_k$. But I have no idea how to define the corresponding ''signed $k$-volume''.

**Problem:** The function $\sqrt{\det(A^TA)}$ (assuming positive real square root) is not multilinear in the columns of $A$. It can be made multilinear by choosing an appropriate sign $\pm\sqrt{\det(A^TA)}$, depending somehow on the matrix $A$, but I don't know how to choose the sign in a systematic way. In the square case, the correct sign is just the sign of $\det(A)$.

More generally, I guess I want to understand the volume form on a $k$-submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ induced by the standard (determinant) volume form on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: $A^TA$ is positive-semidefinite so I don't think it can be made as a multilinear form. At best, maybe in a convex cone. Choosing a sign will still restrict you to the union of two convex cones. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone

Comment: If you want a signed volume, you need to pick a basis on the column space of $A$. E.g. you may pick an orthonormal basis $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_k$ for the column space of $A$, put the basis vectors to form an $n\times k$ matrix $U$, and define the signed volume of the parallelepiped generated by the columns of $A$ as $\det(U^TA)$.

Comment: There is no such volume form. You have to specify an orientation on the submanifold (or, indeed, on a $k$-dimensional subspace). This is not induced from the orientation on the ambient space.